# How can I show different views in a view controller for debugging than release on iOS (using storyboards)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

Using storyboards and supporting iOS8 and up, I'm trying to implement a settings screen that has a few extra options when debugging, is there an easy way to do this, using autolayout? (For various reasons, I'm not using a settings bundle, and I definitely can't start)

Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to modify constraints for every item that doesn't appear in the release version manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is possible only in code with macros

```
#ifndef DEBUG
// release code
// modify views, constraints, etc.
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a shame, but if I group them all into their own view, it shouldn't be too arduous..